# Inexistent double decrement?

Tags: c++, debugging

I was writing a little game, where there is an hidden word, and the user must guess, char to char, what word is.
While coding this I got stucked in something that I don't understeand where and how it happens.

```
while(true)
{
    if(Hue == 0)
        Try -= 1;

    if(Hue == 1)
        Hue = 0;

    GotoXY(0, 3);
    printf("Inserisci una lettera maiuscola\n>");
    GotoXY(1, 4);
    scanf("%c", &Key);
    GotoXY(0, 4);
    printf("        ");

    GotoXY(0, 6);
    printf("Numero di tentativi rimasti: %d ", Try);

    for(unsigned short Iterator = 1; Iterator < Length - 1; ++Iterator)
        if(Key == UserString[Iterator])
        {
            for(unsigned short SecIterator = Iterator; SecIterator < Length - 1; ++SecIterator)
            {
                if(Key == UserString[SecIterator])
                {
                    GotoXY(SecIterator, 1);
                    printf("%c", Key);
                }
            }

            Hue = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hue is a simple control variable to check if the key was in the word.
If it's still 0 then the key wasn't in the word, so the Try decrements it self and so on.

But what happen is that Hue, either is 0 or 1 causes the decrement of Try, and the thing even more stange is that Try decrement twice when is 0, evenly in the code isn't written nothing like that.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where are these variables declared?  What type are all these variables?

Comment: Hue and Try are two unsigned short, UserString is a char*

Comment: @nhgrif: Which conventions?

Comment: Why don't you start the comparison with Iterator at index 0? In a word or two, how would you explain to a colleague what you are trying to do in this nested for/if/for/if/break construct?

Comment: Is `Try` initialized properly when entering the `while ()`?

Comment: Yes, `Try` was initialized at 16 before the loop

Comment: It might not be related to your problem, but you should be careful not to decrement `Try` when it is `0`.

Comment: @blackbird In the `Impiccato` game the word you have is hidden like this `W__D` so the first letter is pointless to check.
The first `for` is for checking if the `Key` is present in the string, if there is, the second `for` start scanning the string and replace every occurrence of the `Key`. Once this is happen, the first `for` is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the confusion is mostly due to the double decrement: well, you are reading `char`s and most likely you hit return making two `char`s available: the entered character and the `'\n'` from the return. Since apparently neither character matches you get two decrements.

Just for a bit of explanation: when using the formatted input using `std::cin >> Key` leading whitespace is skipped. When using `scanf("%c", &c)` each character is extracted. I *think* you can have `scanf()` skip leading spaces using

```
if (1 == scanf(" %c", &c)) {
    // process the input
}
```

Note the extra space in front of the '%c'. To debug issues like this it is generally a good idea to print what was read. ...and, of course, you always need to verify that the read was actually successful.

Comment: Using `std::cin >> Key` instead of `scanf` should alleviate the problem.

Comment: @blackbird Replacing `scanf` with `cin` actually worked! Thanks